# how to calculate the time spent on each page with googleAnalyticsR

Tags: r, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-r

"I am analyzing Google Analytics data using the R library "googleAnalyticsR".
I would like to calculate the time spent on each page of a website, but I cannot find a predefined metric for this.
By cross-referencing the metric 'userEngagementDuration' with the dimension 'pageTitle', can one obtain the time spent on each page?
Is there a way to also calculate the average view duration on each page per user?